# react navigation process when user log in and log out in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have two bottom tab navigator. A, B.

Both of them has login, logout.

Don't ask me why both of them has.

When user log in and log out, I want to reset all of stack and go to stack A.

```
 const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "A" })]
  });

  goToA = () => {
   props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
  }
```

when I login in stack A, there are no problem. but when I login in stack B
It crashes. because in B there are no A route name.

how can I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might find solution.

previously, I put stack navigator into each switch navigator.

But it's not efficient.

I should put switch navigator into stack navigator.

if you have more efficient way to solve this, feel free to tell me.

Thanks!

Comment: yes, that's the use of switch navigator we should use it in those cases when we want A -> B & B will replace A.